# Efficiently write csv from spark based on filter query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a task that I'm trying to do in pyspark and I'm 100% sure there is a more efficient way to tackle it. Basically, I have a table with a few hundred binary columns and I want to write out a single .csv *for each column* with a sample of the rows that have a 1 for that column. Hence, if I have 500 columns, I would like to end up with 500 different .csv files.

My current code is:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from table WHERE col_a = 1 LIMIT 1000" )
df = df.coalesce(1)
df.write\
    .mode('overwrite')\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .csv("s3://my_bucket/" + col_a + "/")
```

As I'm currently doing it, it just loops through all the columns in pyspark and runs that snippet on each. However, this doesn't take advantage of any of the EMR because, while the sql query can be map/reduced, writing to a single csv then has to use a single node and the rest of the cluster just sits there waiting.

My question is: is there a way to tell spark to do something like send the different iterations of the loop out to all the nodes and do them in parallel? (I don't mean it has to be in a literal loop, just that concept.)

Or, barring that, can anyone think of a creative, more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

NOTES:

1) the purpose of this is feed these .csv's to a python machine learning script, so writing these to a different table instead of to .csv files is not an option. Writing to some other kind of file would be fine, but I think that's beside the point.

2) having it be a random sample is not important, so using `LIMIT` is fine.

Comment: `foreachPartitionAsync` maybe ?

Comment: Not sure about Pyspark but this function should help in Scala/Java  public DataFrameWriter<T> partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq<String> colNames)

Comment: Could you add an argument for the column name and have a shell script do multiple spark-submits?

Comment: Another potential option write some code to build up the query: SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 1 AS ID from TABLE WHERE colA=1 LIMIT 1000 UNION ALL SELECT *, 2 AS ID FROM TABLE WHERE colB=1 LIMIT 1000) ORDER BY ID .... Then save and split the resulting file every 1000 lines.

Comment: @ayplam, to your first comment, would that send each job to different nodes? I don't know very much about how spark-submit allocates cluster resources. This might be the right idea.

Comment: The way I understand it, YARN figures out which node(s) has enough resources for the job, then allocates that memory to run the job. So if you submit two jobs, and your cluster has enough memory for both jobs, it'll run both. If it only has enough for one job, the second spark-submit will wait for the first to finish before running.